# Starting from an expression of E(V) and P(V) for the Birch-Murnaghan's equation of state, is there a way of obtaining an expression for E(P)?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, differentiation

I have a function, an equation of state named the Birch-Murnaghan's equation of state, in which the Energy ( $E$ ) is a function of the Volume ($V$), where $E_{0}$, $V_{0}$, $B_{0}$ and $B_{0}^{'}$ are parameters that can be obtained from the fit:

\begin{equation}
\label{BM-EOS-Energy-Volume}
E\left ( V \right )=E_{0}+\frac{9V_{0}B_{0}}{16}\left \{ \left [ \left ( \frac{V_{0}}{V} \right  )^\frac{2}{3} -1 \right ]^3 B_{0}^{'}+\left [ \left ( \frac{V_{0}}{V} \right )^{\frac{2}{3}}-1 \right ]^{2}\left [ 6-4\left (\frac{V_0}{V}  \right )^{\frac{2}{3}} \right ]\right \},   \tag{1}
\end{equation}

The pressure P may be written as a function of the volume V as:

\begin{equation}
\label{BM-EOS-Energy-Volume-derivative}
P\left ( V \right )=-\left ( \frac{\partial E}{\partial V} \right )_{S}, \tag{2}
\end{equation}

so that we can get the expression of $P\left ( V \right )$ :
\begin{equation}
\label{BM-EOS-Pressure-Volume}
P\left ( V \right )=\frac{3B_{0}}{2}\left [ \left ( \frac{V_{0}}{V} \right )^\frac{7}{3} - \left ( \frac{V_{0}}{V} \right )^\frac{5}{3}\right ]\left \{ 1+\frac{3}{4}\left ( B_{0}^{'}-4 \right )\left [ \left ( \frac{V_{0}}{V} \right )^\frac{2}{3}-1 \right ] \right \} \tag{3}
\end{equation}

Now, I would like to get an expression of $E(P)$, but I do not find the way  to accomplish that goal starting from the expression of $E(V)$ (Equation 1) and $P(V)$ (Equation 3).

I would appreciate if you could help me.

**EDIT**:

I have data of $E$ vs $V$. After plotting, I have fitted this data using Eq. (1).

I have transformed each $V$ data to $P$ using Eq. (3).

I have now plotted $P$ vs $V$, and fitted using Eq. (3).

Now I have plotted $E$ vs $P$ and I need to fit this data using a function. And this function would have to be the expression of $E(P)$, which I don't know a possible way of working it out.

Comment: You could try to manually eliminate $V$.

Comment: Whoops ... comment deleted.

Comment: @Karlo In the hypothetical case you were to eliminate $V$ from Eq. 1, you would not end up with an expression of $E(P)$

Comment: @DavidC - you misunderstood Karlo's obvious recipe. You clearly can't eliminate $V$ just from equation 1. You need to elimininate $V$ from the set of equations 1,3. These are two equations involving $E,P,V$, if you eliminate $V$, i.e. find a combination of 1,3 that has no $V$, you will have an equation with $E,P$ only which is an implicit (or explicit, if you are lucky) prescription for $E=E(P)$.

Comment: @LubošMotl There is no possible way to describe a combination of Equations 1,3 that have no $V$

Comment: BTW, the mark-up `\tag{tag text}` is the usual way to number equations in MathJax (and the way to force the numbering in LaTeX, though forcing it is usually discouraged in favor of automatic schemes). I've done yours.

Comment: @DavidC - the problem to eliminate V may be mathematically hard and the solution may fail to be analytic but a function that solves it obviously exists.

Comment: @LubošMotl `a function that solves it obviously exists` Really?  do you know what is that function?

Comment: @LubošMotl See the **EDIT**

Comment: The function may be ill-defined for some values of $P$ - it may be legalized by saying that the range of $P$  is limited - and the function may have several values of $E$ for a given argument $P$ - however, only one of them is right in certain circumstances. With these disclaimers, the function exists and is obtained by elimination of $V$ which is a purely mathematical task. You can always do it numerically, can't you? For each value of $P$ you're interested in (e.g. all), find the value of $V$ from eq 3 and substitute this $V$ to eq 1 to get $E$. What the hell is the problem?

Comment: @LubošMotl `the function exists and is obtained by elimination of V which is a purely mathematical task`. That is what I am looking for, the analytical expression of $E(P)$, but I can't find the way for that `purely mathematical task`

Answer (score 2):

This is the purpose of the Legendre transform, which lies at the core of hamiltonian mechanics. You have a function $E(V,S)$, which is convex for certain interval of $V$, and want to find $E'(P,S)$, where $P \equiv -\left.\frac{\partial E}{\partial V}\right|_S$. This function is given by the Legendre transform of $E$:
$$E'(P,S) = PV + E(V,S)$$ for the interval of $V$ in which $E$ is convex.

Comment: Does that mean that $E(P)$ is simply $E(P) = PV + E_{0}+\frac{9V_{0}B_{0}}{16}\left \{ \left [ \left ( \frac{V_{0}}{V} \right  )^\frac{2}{3} -1 \right ]^3 B_{0}^{'}+\left [ \left ( \frac{V_{0}}{V} \right )^{\frac{2}{3}}-1 \right ]^{2}\left [ 6-4\left (\frac{V_0}{V}  \right )^{\frac{2}{3}} \right ]\right \}$ ?

Comment: @DavidC. Yes, but there is the problem that $E(V,S)$ is convex in a small interval and may not be what you need.

Comment: @DavidC. Also, I know that many physicists (me included) abuse notation and write $E(P)$, when in fact they mean "a function that takes values of pressure and returns energy", but in mathematical terms $E(P)$ means $E(V)$ if you replace $V\mapsto P$, which doesn't make sense and may confuse you.